# Display MONGODB data in React.js page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to display a collection from MongoDB inside a React webpage, with no success so far.

I got the data as json in the backend but I am not sure how to bring it to frontend.

The data I get looks like this:

```
{
      _id: 60d5ee8d9f3b772030ae319c,
      username: 'test',
      email: 'test@test.com',
      password: '$2a$10$5F8k.qfP3Bi7vlLKuOxcneejlsnxB4cN1SerV7tFkAS6v2E.YhBqK',
      __v: 0
    }
```

This is where I am trying to display the data:

```
    import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
    import "./PrivateScreen.css";
    
    const PrivateScreen = ({ history }) => {
      const [error, setError] = useState("");
      const [privateData, setPrivateData] = useState("");
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (!localStorage.getItem("authToken")) {
          history.push("login");
        }
    
        const fetchPrivateDate = async () => {
          const config = {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("authToken")}`,
            },
          };
    
          try {
            const { data } = await axios.get("/api/private", config);
            setPrivateData(data.data);
          } catch (error) {
            localStorage.removeItem("authToken");
            setError("You are not authorized please login");
          }
        };
    
        fetchPrivateDate();
      }, [history]);
    
      const logoutHandler = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem("authToken");
        history.push("/login");
      };
    
      return error ? (
        <span className="error-message">{error}</span>
      ) : (
        <>
          <div style={{ background: "green", color: "white" }}>{privateData}</div>
          <button onClick={logoutHandler}>Logout</button>
          <div>DISPLAY THE DATA HERE<div/>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default PrivateScreen;
```

The actual data I will get will be big, and I know I have to map it, but first I need to get to this step :D.
Could someone please give me a few hints, and sorry if I didn't give enough details, I will try and give more information if you guys require it.

Thank you, have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

As you are storing the data in the `privateData` state, you can access that data in the whole function, here is an example of what you can do.

```
return error ? (
   <span className="error-message">{error}</span>
) : (
   <>
     <div style={{ background: "green", color: "white" }}>{privateData}</div>
     <button onClick={logoutHandler}>Logout</button>
     <div>email: {privateData.email}, username: {privateData.username}<div/>
   </>
);
```

or if `privateData` is an array you can show the data helping `map`, here is another example:

```
return error ? (
   <span className="error-message">{error}</span>
) : (
   <>
     <div style={{ background: "green", color: "white" }}>{privateData}</div>
     <button onClick={logoutHandler}>Logout</button>
     <div>{privateData.map((el) => {
       return (
         el.username
       )
     })}<div/>
   </>
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The data I am trying to get from MongoDB, unfortunately is not in privateData. that is just a message I am displaying after a successful login.

At the moment this is the only way I got to display the data from Mongo in a console.log in the backend:

`const connectDB = async () => {
  mongoose.connect(
    process.env.MONGO_URI,

    function (err, db) {
      var cursor = db.collection("users").find();
      cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
        var data = doc;
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  );`